# Django: How to concatenate translation and constant string in template

Tags: python, django, templates, translation, string-concatenation

I'd like to pass a translation with variable to template tag. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
{% my_tag _("Entries for tag")|add:" '"|add:tag|add:"'" %}
```

But this does not work. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `<span>{% my_tag _("Entries for tag") %} '{{tag}}'</span>`

Comment: Thanks for answer.
my_tag outputs some HTML, and I need the '{{tag}}' to be inside of that HTML.

Comment: Then you should send the `tag` as an argument of your `my_tag` function and add it in your code. Then it would be as simple as `{% my_tag _("Entries for tag") tag %}`. Please see the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: The problem is that the structure of string is not related to my_tag anyhow. The tag already accepts few arguments, and the first one is a string that I want to compile from two parts. I may decide to use three or more parts tomorrow, or even to pass the string to some third-party tag. So, this is no a right solution. I need to prepare the string before I pass it to a tag.

Comment: If you don't want to do it in the html after the custom tag, and you don't want to send it as an argument, I don't know how to help. Hope you either re-think your problem or someone more experienced can help.

Comment: Thank you for help. Now I'm writing {% endmytag %} to make it possible to pass complex content, but this is not what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would probably be:

```html
{% blocktrans with tag=tag %}
    <span>Entries for tag</span> '{{ tag }}'
{% endblocktrans %}
```

But putting HTML inside translated strings is not the best idea. What is much worse though is assuming that you can just concatenate a translation of an English string with another string and get a valid sentence. You can never assume that position of `{{ tag }}` withing the sentence will be the same in other languages. Some language will probably need the translation to be `Lorem ipsum „%(tag)s” dolor sit`.

But it seems you're trying to apply some HTML dynamically. Maybe what you really want is to `ugettext('Entries for tag %(tag)s')` inside `my_tag` and parse it accordingly (say find `%(tag)s` and add some HTML around it).

Comment: Thanks.
As I said above, my_tag (means _template tag_) knows nothing about the text it receives, about translations, tags (means _keywords_ like "python, django, templates, translation" for this question) etc. And actually I've got similar problem with another third-party template tag before. So, changing the template tag code is not the way. What I want is to know how to concatenate translated string with another one (or better to translate string with variable) before I pass it to any tag, like it is possible with plain strings using filter 'add'.

Comment: The best solution would be to pass the result of blocktrans tag to another tag as a parameter, but it seems there is no elegant way to do so. The only way is to write new template tag that will set the context variable. Seems ugly, does not?